# how can i insert data into two table at a time?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to execte both querys, but insertion will happen on one table(first query only). If i put query9 first, it will execute, otherwise query3.

```
$query9 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO complete_status (ID, hotel_id, 
floor_id, room_id, pull_chrdsw_status, emergency_status, nurse_callsw_status, cmr_status, foodsw_status, bedside_cancelsw_status ,nurse_distress_status, bcssw_status ,final_status,date1, Time) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");           
$query9->bind_param("iiiiiiiiiiiii", $ID, $HotelID ,$SectorID, $RoomID, $pull_chrdsw_status, $emergency_status, $nurse_callsw_status, $cmr_status, $foodsw_status,$bedside_cancelsw_status, $nurse_distress_status, $bcssw_status,$statuss);


if($value->NurseCallSwStats != $Uploadedpkt->RoomStatus[$key]->NurseCallSwStats)
{
    if($DebugMode===TRUE)// Test mode with debugg outputs
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "laundry change";
    }
    $Difference_Flag=TRUE;
    $nurse_callsw_status = $Uploadedpkt->RoomStatus[$key]->NurseCallSwStats;
    $query3->execute();
    $query9->execute(); 
}   


foreach ($Uploadedpkt->RoomStatus as $key => $value) 
{   
    $nurse_callsw_status = $Uploadedpkt->RoomStatus[$key]->NurseCallSwStats;
    $query3->execute(); 
    $query9->execute(); 
}
```

Comment: Look for stored procedure or trigger event! After your search, if you still want to run these two queries one after one (it is not a bad), you can easily protect your data with InnoDb tables and transactions (With a transaction activated, if query9 failed, query3 isn't committed rollbacked, it is rollbacked) Transaction are not available for MyIsam tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `stored procedure` that contains all your queries and then execute it.